# Nextjs; Blurry text in component on some mobile devices

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, tailwind-css, framer-motion

As the title said I continue to have the issue, that some text on my nextjs page appears blurry, but online on some mobile devices. I noticed it most with some iPhones. This is true for mobile devices and if I use the console to test mobile layout. This is only an issue for two components I have on my page. Both are cards you can flip in order to view the backside. They are also animated with Framermotion. Styles are done with Tailwind Regular text on other sections of the page appears normally.

Here is an example image so you can see what i mean. Larger text seems to be fine but smaller text is blurry. I only included a screenshot of the front face. The back face has the same issue.

[image]

The corresponding Code for this component is here:

```ts
'use client';
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { motion } from 'framer-motion';
import { fadeIn } from '../../../utils/motion';

function ProjectCard({ index, id, title, icons, description, ghlink, pagelink }: any) {
    return (
        <motion.div
            variants={fadeIn('right', 'spring', index * 0.1, 1.75)}
            initial="hidden"
            whileInView="show"
            key={id}
            className="w-[280px] md:w-[300px] h-[440px] cursor-pointer group perspective my-4 md:m-6"
        >
            <div className="w-full h-full absolute border-2 rounded-[15px] preserve-3d group-hover:flip-cardY duration-500">
                {/* FRONT FACE */}
                <div className="absolute w-full h-full glassmorphism rounded-[15px] backface-hidden text-center flex flex-col items-center justify-between z-50">
                    <h3 className="pt-8 font-bold text-[26px] gap-4 text-[#18BC9C]">{title}</h3>
                    <div className="flex flex-row flex-wrap items-center justify-center md:m-1 z-50">
                        {icons.map(
                            (icon: any, id: any) => (
                                <p key={id} className="rounded-[25px] text-[10px] bg-[#34acc7] py-1 px-2 m-1 tracking-wide">#{icon}</p>
                            ))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <p className="text-[12px] font-bold text-[#18BC9C] p-3">Hover for more Info!</p>
                </div>
                {/* BACK FACE */}
                <div className="absolute w-full h-full bg-[#2E3A59] rounded-[15px] backface-hidden flip-cardY text-center flex flex-col p-2 items-center justify-between z-50">
                    <h3 className="p-4 font-bold text-[22px] gap-4 text-[#18BC9C]">ABOUT THIS PROJECT</h3>
                    <p className="text-[15px] text-justify">
                        {description}
                    </p>
                    <div className="flex flex-row gap-6 m-4 bottom-0">
                        {ghlink &&
                            <>
                                <Link href={ghlink} target="_blank">
                                    <Image alt="github" src="github.svg" width={25} height={25} className='py-2 md:w-[40px] md:h-[40px] object-contain hover:scale-150 duration-200' />
                                </Link>
                            </>
                        }
                        {pagelink &&
                            <>
                                <Link href={pagelink} target="_blank">
                                    <Image alt="homepage" src="link.svg" width={25} height={25} className='py-2 md:w-[40px] md:h-[40px] object-contain hover:scale-150 duration-200' />
                                </Link>
                            </>
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </motion.div>
    )
};

export default ProjectCard;
```

I tried removing styles and also the framer motion animations aswell as tyring to find a solution by making another component from scratch and trying to find the error along the way. Neither seemed to be the solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Presumably, the rest of your app is not blurred? I'm certain this is something to do with your CSS, what's the `glassmorphism` class?

Comment: Exactly, the rest is fine. I also lean into the direction that the styles might be to blame. glassmorphism is just the background effect you can see in the screenshot. I removed it to try to get the desired improvement but this did not change anything

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I still could not find a helpful answer anywhere else. I just made the text bigger which helped a bit. The text still seems blurry to me but at least now it is readable. What I also fin interesting is, that the text gets sharp once you hover on the card and it starts turning around.

Bur for now the only solution was to just set the text to 13px instead of the initial 10px